# Import phone internal/external images into my app with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new in android development. I am trying to import phone gallery images into my app via recyclerview. I've tried to use this link: [import gallery images which are stored in phone/memory card into recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154915/import-gallery-images-which-are-stored-in-phone-memory-card-into-recyclerview)  but where should I place this code? I tried in recyclerview adapter and in my fragment, but getContentResolver() method is red (Cannot resolve method getContentResolver()) is written. I changed this with Context context object, but nullPointerException error show me in log. everithing works fine with json, with picasso but I need to import them from my phone's gallery.

Here is my code:

**RecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
public class MyCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter.Holder> {

    private List<CalendarPojo> calendarImagesList;
    Context context;

    public MyCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter() {
        calendarImagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.calendar_image_item, parent, false);
        return new Holder(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {

        CalendarPojo calendarObject = calendarImagesList.get(position);
     /*   String link = calendarObject.getImage();
      //  Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(link).into(holder.imageView); */
          imageMediaQuery();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return calendarImagesList.size();
    }

    public void addCalendarImages(CalendarPojo calendarPojo) {
        calendarImagesList.add(calendarPojo);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView imageView;


        public Holder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.select_image_calendar);
        }
    }

    private void imageMediaQuery() {
        Context context;
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                //MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN
        };

        Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String BUCKET_GROUP_BY =
                "1) GROUP BY 1,(1";
        String BUCKET_ORDER_BY = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";

        Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(images,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                BUCKET_GROUP_BY,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                BUCKET_ORDER_BY        // Ordering
        );

        if(cur!=null){
            Log.i("ListingImages", " query count=" + cur.getCount());
        }


        if (cur!=null&&cur.moveToFirst()) {
            String bucket;
            String path;
            int bucketColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

            int pathColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(
                    MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);

            do {
                bucket = cur.getString(bucketColumn);
                path = cur.getString(pathColumn);

            } while (cur.moveToNext());
            cur.close();

        }
    }
}
```

**CalendarFragment.java**

```
package ge.softservice.photobucket;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import ge.softservice.photobucket.controller.RestManager;
import ge.softservice.photobucket.model.CalendarPojo;
import ge.softservice.photobucket.model.Printing;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link CalendarFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link CalendarFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    protected RecyclerView recyclerView;
    protected MyCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter myCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RestManager mManager;


    public CalendarFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment NavCalendarFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static CalendarFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        CalendarFragment fragment = new CalendarFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        mManager = new RestManager();
        Call<List<CalendarPojo>> listCall = mManager.getGalleryImageService().getCalendarImages();
        listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<CalendarPojo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<CalendarPojo>> call, Response<List<CalendarPojo>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<CalendarPojo> calendarList = response.body();

                    for (int i = 0; i <calendarList.size() ; i++) {
                        CalendarPojo calendar = calendarList.get(i);
                        myCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter.addCalendarImages(calendar);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    int sc = response.code();
                    switch (sc) {

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<CalendarPojo>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_fragment, container, false);
        myCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_recycler_view);
/*        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext(), 2);*/
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 3);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        ( (AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.calendars);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

/*    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }*/

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the context as an argument.

```
public MyCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter(Context from) {
    calendarImagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    context = from;
}
```

So where you instantiate (if it's a Activity): `new MyCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter(this)`
if it is a fragment: `new MyCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity())`

Also you could had loaded the files with the full-qualified-path-name if you know exactly which is like: `InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("/sdcard/Download/pictures/image1.png"))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but here:         Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(images,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                BUCKET_GROUP_BY,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // Selection arguments (none)
                BUCKET_ORDER_BY        // Ordering
        ); but here "getContentResolver()" is still red

Comment: replace "this" for "context", you will have one now

Comment: I think my problem is in BindView Holder. '@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Holder holder, int position) {

/*        CalendarPojo calendarObject = calendarImagesList.get(position);
        String link = calendarObject.getImage();
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(uri).into(holder.imageView);*/
      //  Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        imageMediaQuery();
    }'   How can I insert imageMediaQuery(); in BindViewHolder? and should be this method in RecyclerViewAdapter?

Comment: You can externalize it on a responsible class, but are you sure that it will return only one image? Don't you know the exactly path for the image file?

Comment: No, not one. I need to import all of my images stored in phone memory and sd card

Comment: So you need to load all images before onBindView method, and at the method just load the exactly one that is the row

Comment: How can I do it technically?

Comment: Before you call new MyCalendarRecyclerViewAdapter, loads all in an List and pass it to the object created.